# Handling escape characters when using csv file format as source in SSIS

Tags: ssis

How to escape double quotes when using csv file as the input in SSIS when the csv file has default  comma seprated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the `double quotes` within the CSV file's column data, please refer my answer in [**this Stack Overflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210744/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-derived-column-in-ssis/6213833#6213833). The example in the question explains how to replace/remove double quotes using `Derived Column Transformation` task.

Hope that helps.