# SSIS Text Qualifier not working correctly

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, ssis

I have a CSV file I am importing through SSIS.Below is an sample of the data in my file

"MEM1001","OTHER","P" ,20101001,20781231,,20781231,20101001,
"Medic","General >21"                               ,
"A100100"                   ,"2210",20101001,20781231

I have added , as column delimiter and " as Text Qualifier in the connection manager.

But columns like "P" ,"Medic","General >21"                               ,"A100100"                   ,  are still coming enclosed with double quotes when I preview the data while rest the of the string columns are coming without double quotes.
I am guessing it has something to do with the spaces after the quotes.

Can somebody explain why this is happening and how can i make this columns to come without double quotes while importing the data from file to table.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this post, I had the same issues, I was trying around and could not find any other solution.

The text qualifier " only works in csv files, when the quote is directly after the colon, no space after the colon and the text identifier/qualifier. I have no idea why.

If you aren't able to fix the input data, an option would be to create a derived column and to replace the double quotes.
This worked for me:
[How to replace double quotes in derived column transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210744/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-derived-column-transformation)

```
Trim(REPLACE(COLA, "\"", ""))
```

You should also add the Trim(), otherwise you have empty spaces before and maybe after the word. This could be problematic in a merge join (in my case it was).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just go to the Connection Manager for that csv file, click on Columns, and under the Column delimiter box just enter a space followed by a comma?  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this extra spaces cause this issue.

Here is what I would do. It may not be the best idea, but it should work.

You will need to add script task before data flow task that would replace all " ," and ", " to ",".

Thank you