# SSIS Derived Column Transformation Editor

Tags: csv, ssis, delimiter, derived-column

I have a csv file that I'm loading into a database
example of content of csv

```
"name","house,up a hill","drive"
```

I have set the column delimiter to be ", within the connection manager

which gives me data in 3 columns

```
column 1 =   "name 
column 2 = house,up a hill
column 3 = drive"
```

I need to then remove any " from any of the text in the three columns I have added Derived Column to my package and and added the following

```
REPLACE(column 1,'"','')
```

this hasn't worked, I thought the replace worked as column name, text to replace, replace with

any help would be appriciated

Comment: DERIVED COLUMN uses double quotetation and not single. So use " and not ' when you write something in your derived column expressions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace double quotes in derived column transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210744/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-derived-column-transformation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like this in your derived column task

```
REPLACE( [COLUMNAME],"\"","")
```